# Java, MyBatis 3.4, huge batch inserts are not actually stored to DB at once

Tags: java, mysql, mybatis

Task: i need to do at least 10k records inserts as a one batch.

In reality: During the commit/flush calls I can see by using "SELECT * FROM TABLE" that records are inserted by totally random numbers. 
Like it can insert 1k, then 500, then another 1.5k, then again 500. Some really weird stuff is going on with this batching.

I have really basic setup, as:

```
<bean id="armDataSource"
          class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">
        <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${database.url}"/>
        <property name="user" value="${database.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}"/>
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="30"/>
        <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="300"/>
        <property name="maxIdleTime" value="300"/>
        <property name="preferredTestQuery" value="SELECT 1"/>
        <property name="testConnectionOnCheckin" value="true"/>
    </bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="armTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="armDataSource"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="armSqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="armDataSource"/>
        <property name="typeAliasesPackage" value="com.database.arm.model"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="armSqlSessionTemplate" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate">
        <constructor-arg index="0" ref="armSqlSessionFactory" />
        <constructor-arg index="1" value="BATCH" />
    </bean>
```

Then i have the following code:

```
SqlSession sqlSession = armSqlSessionTemplate.getSqlSessionFactory().openSession(ExecutorType.BATCH, false);
        HeaderMapper headerMapper = sqlSession.getMapper(HeaderMapper.class);
        List<List<HeaderDAO>> partitions = Lists.partition(HeaderDAOS, 10000);
                partitions.forEach(partition -> {
                    partition.forEach(headerDAO -> {
                        headerDAO.setFileId(fileId);
                        headerMapper.insert(headerDAO);
                    });
    sqlSession.flushStatements();
    });
        sqlSession.commit();
        sqlSession.close();
```

It works just fine with small batch inserts of 100 or less records. But once i go higher, it looks like mybatis doing more then one batch.

Maybe there is some problem with the setup of sqlSessionFactory or template or dataSource? I've tried so many options but neither helped.
Any input is very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So I have debugged all the stack till mysql driver and have found the reason.
By default, MySQL driver actually performs batch inserts one by one in one transaction.
To enable one big batch insert, you need to let mysqldriver know it, by using property:

> rewriteBatchedStatements=true

This can be bypassed in the connectionUrl for the datasource, or specified via properties of the datasource:

```
<property name="properties">
    <props>
        <prop key="rewriteBatchedStatements">true</prop>
    </props>
</property>
```

P.S.: You need to use it only in case of MyBatis, because for instance, Hibernate will do it automatically.